# Downloaded model has no materials or textures

Tags: import, 3d, textures, blender, fbx

Below I've shown what the downloaded model should of looked like and what it looks like in blender

[image01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3e5g.jpg)

[image02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttOc9.png)

I've tried manually adding the textures but it takes way too long. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It can be tricky finding textures try external data > find missing textures

If that doesn't work I found this addon helpful blendermarket.com/products/super-importer-